# Fetch request required after decoding into a NSManagedObject object

Tags: ios, swift, nsmanagedobject, decodable

I have the following generic function that works: it correctly creates the objects and I know is saved into core data because if do a fetch request right after, I get the object I just created. However, the object itself isn't a valid core data object (x-core data fault). Is there any way around so I don't have to do a fetch request right after a decoding an object? Many thanks.

```
func decode<T: Decodable>(data: Data?, objectType: T.Type, save: Bool = true, completionHandler: @escaping (T) -> ())
{
    guard let d = data else { return }
    do
    {
        let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateContext.parent = SingletonDelegate.shared.context

        let root = try JSONDecoder(context: privateContext).decode(objectType, from: d)

        if save
        {
            try privateContext.save()
            privateContext.parent?.performAndWait
            {
                do
                {
                    if let p = privateContext.parent
                    {
                        try p.save()
                    }

                }catch
                {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            completionHandler(root)
        }
    }catch
    {
        print(error)
    }
}

extension CodingUserInfoKey 
{
    static let context = CodingUserInfoKey(rawValue: "context")!
}


extension JSONDecoder 
{
    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) 
    {
        self.init()
        self.userInfo[.context] = context
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A core data fault *is* a valid Core Data object; it just hasn't been retrieved from the backing store into memory yet.

To reduce memory use, Core Data only fetches the full object when you access one of its properties.  This fetch is automatic and effectively transparent to your code.

This means you don't need to do anything special; you can just use the managed object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I print an attribute of the object, it is empty

Comment: Where does the `JSONDecoder(context:)` initialiser come from?  Have you added an extension to `JSONDecoder` ?

Comment: Yes, I have added it on the question. Im trying to layout a VIPER architecture, and in the store its fine, (no fault). However, on the worker that handles this store (passed by closures), it is empty (fault).

Comment: A fault isn't empty; it simply represents an object that hasn't been fetched yet. Accessing a property should cause the fault to fire.  Is the object ID of the fault the same as the object id you get if you perform a fetch?  The problem may be that you are creating the object in a child store; Objects in a child store aren't persisted in the persistent store.  The parent context does that.  You may need to use `object(with:)` on the parent store to get the object you need

Comment: No, indeed is not the same. The decoded object's objectID has an extra / and the hash starts with t.

Comment: OK. my problem is that when I first create the object, it doesn't have a persistent store assigned

Comment: That is to be expected. Child managed object contexts don’t have a persistent Store. That is why you need to call `save` on the parent store.

Comment: I am saving the parent moc on p.save(). The completionHandler should be after performAndWait, but nothing works. Thanks anyway